# Concatenating numbers in virtual column expression throws ORA-12899: value too large for column

Tags: oracle, numbers, sqldatatypes, oracle12c, virtual-column

While I gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28542897/3989608) to a question yesterday, I suggested to use a **VIRTUAL COLUMN** for computed values instead of manually updating it.

I did a test myself, and figured out an issue with the data size that the virtual column expression takes while **concatenating** two **NUMBER** type columns. Though, no issue while concatenating two characters.

**DB version :**

```
SQL> select banner from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

**Test case 1 : Concatenating strings**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID varchar2(2),
  3  num varchar2(2),
  4  text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as (id||'_'||num) VIRTUAL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES ('a', 'e');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES ('b', 'f');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES ('c', 'g');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

ID NU TEXT
-- -- ----------
a  e  a_e
b  f  b_f
c  g  c_g

SQL>
```

So, no issues with concatenating two character type columns.

**Test case 2 : concatenating numbers**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  num NUMBER,
  4  text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as (to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num)) VIRTUAL
  5  );
text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as (to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num)) VIRTUAL
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEXT" (actual: 10, maximum: 81)
```

Not allowed? Huh! Let's increase the size -

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  num NUMBER,
  4  text VARCHAR2(81) generated always as (to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num)) VIRTUAL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (1, 4);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (2, 5);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (3, 6);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

        ID        NUM
---------- ----------
TEXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          4
1_4

         2          5
2_5

         3          6
3_6


SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

        ID        NUM TEXT
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          4 1_4
         2          5 2_5
         3          6 3_6

SQL>
```

So what happened now? Table got created, but why **VIRTUAL COLUMN** occupies that much size when the **expected data size is just 3 bytes**, however it takes **81 bytes**.

Checking the **length**, value is correct, however, the data size is much larger. For example, I expect the length to be 3, so I declare the size of the column as 10 bytes. But the virtual column expression yields the value with a size much more than that.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  num NUMBER,
  4  text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as (length(to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num))) VIRTUAL
  5  );
text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as (length(to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num))) VIRTUAL
*
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEXT" (actual: 10, maximum: 40)


SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  num NUMBER,
  4  text VARCHAR2(81) generated always as (length(to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num))) VIRTUAL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (1, 4);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (2, 5);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (3, 6);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

        ID        NUM TEXT
---------- ---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          4 3
         2          5 3
         3          6 3

SQL> clear columns
columns cleared
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

        ID        NUM TEXT
---------- ---------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1          4 3
         2          5 3
         3          6 3
```

Any insight is more than welcome.

**UDPATE** Thanks to Alex Poole. I did not think about the implicit conversion, so I did not care to CAST the expression explicitly. So, the below works -

```
SQL> DROP TABLE t PURGE;

Table dropped.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(
  2  ID NUMBER,
  3  num NUMBER,
  4  text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as (cast(to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num) as varchar2(3))) VIRTUAL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (1, 4);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (2, 5);

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(ID, num) VALUES (3, 6);

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM T;

        ID        NUM TEXT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4 1_4
         2          5 2_5
         3          6 3_6

SQL>
```

Comment: You are concatenating two _lexicalisations_ of oracle numbers. Given that - according to the docs - each of them may have up to 38 significant digits, the reported error seems fine (add 1 additional position for the sign representation).

Comment: @collapsar, the implicit conversion from number to varchar2 made the expression result with size varchar2(40) for each value. This concatenation itself needs 80 bytes. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your numbers are not constrained. With single digit (positive) numbers *you* know the concatendated length can only be three, but the virtual column has to be large enough for any number - so it looks like it's allowing up to 40 digits for the implicit format model (38 significant digits, the decimal separator, and the sign; @collspar's *lexicalisation*).

Having said that, constraining the number column wouldn't be reflected in the virtual column length - making both columns `NUMBER(1,0)` still leaves the concatenation requiring 81 characters. Taking the substring of the generated value [won't work either](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28370714/266304), in this case getting `ORA-12899: value too large for column "TEXT" (actual: 10, maximum: 40)`. Supplying a format model for each `to_char()` call, e.g. of `FM999`), would work but restricts the values either side of the underscore rather than the overall length directly.

If you want to restrict the column size, you can cast it to the same data type and size, which is more explicit:

```
text VARCHAR2(10) generated always as 
    (cast(to_char(id)||'_'||to_char(num) as VARCHAR2(10))) VIRTUAL
```